# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_9 to have shape (7,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Please help. I'm getting this error on running the training code on colab
want to do multi label classification (7 distinct output labels)

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_9 to have shape (7,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

My code is as follows:

```
with open("data/fer2013/fer2013.csv") as f:
    x_train = np.array(x_train, 'float32')
    y_train = np.array(y_train, 'float32')
    x_test = np.array(x_test, 'float32')
    y_test = np.array(y_test, 'float32')

x_train /= 255 #normalize inputs between [0, 1]
x_test /= 255

x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 48, 48, 1)
x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 48, 48, 1)
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')

model.add(BatchNormalization(input_shape=(48,48,1)))
#1st convolution layer
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2, 2)))

#2nd convolution layer
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2, 2)))

#3rd convolution layer
model.add(Conv2D(256, (2, 2), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2, 2)))

#4th convolution layer
model.add(Conv2D(512, (2, 2), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (2, 2), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1,1), strides=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())

#fully connected neural networks
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax'))

## Start the training    
#model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=epochs, validation_split=0.0, shuffle=True) #train for all trainset
model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_data=(x_test,y_test)) #train for randomly selected one


score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], score[1]*100))


##########################------------------------############################
# serialize model to JSON
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model/model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
# serialize weights to HDF5
model.save_weights("model/weights.h5")
print("Saved model to disk")
############################---------------------###############################
```

want to do multi label classification (7 distinct output labels)
I'm expecting a json file model.json
but i'm getting an error

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_9 to have shape (7,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

Comment: Hi, some more information would be good to better understand your problem. Do you have more layers in your model or only the two seen in the code (error says dense_9, so I'd expect more layers). Where is your train_generator, where do you define num_classes and which line does the error indicate as problem?

Comment: Please show us the loss function you are using and the shape of `y_test`. There is a mismatch between your output dimension and your training labels (targets).